# Circular dependency in between linked .blend, can't have mats in one files and models in another?

Tags: linked-data

So I want a Master .blend files with all my mat, and several linked collections of meshes from other .blend files. I thought this would be no problem but I get a message in console that look like a circular dependency.

What I did is this: create a mat in Master file, link the mat in one of the mesh .blend file for unwrapping and testing, go back to master file and link the mesh. To my surprise I can't see the mat on the mesh, and I get this message:
'Warning: LIB: Data refers to main .blend file: 'MAtest_MatLink' from C:......'

test_MatLink being the name of my mat.

So how can I do this? This is for product rendering so having one mat for all the objects is crucial if I need to make quick changes.

Right ow the only solution I found is to have a dedicated .blend file for  the materials, a Master .blend file that handle rendering with all my python code and appends the collections as needed, and all the blend file for each 3D model with the mat linked from the dedicated mat blend file. Make sense?

It's ok but I'd rather have my mat in the Master.

Comment: You can *append* to create a copy instead of a link and therefore have one file for the asset with mesh and material. Alternatively you can link material and mesh into a third project file for the asset.

Comment: I know about appending but in this case I want everything linked, if I make a change to a mat this need to be repercussed over 12 different 3D models in different .blend files.

Comment: I can recommed Andy's talk from the Blender Conference about their production pipeline for Spring. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=aR3yNNGK_sc

Comment: Well then I'd use a third project where both material and mesh are linked to. The linking structure has to be a tree (no circular dependencies).

Comment: Yep I think the tree analogy makes sense, I'll just have a blend file for mat and another for rendering then.